# divide excel sheet based on spesific cell values

Tags: java, excel, vba, jxl

i have a data sheet in excel about 950000 row with 7 col.and i want to divide it based on V5 col data. V5 holds data for time in seconds into one hour so i need to  [image]divide the data into sheets each sheet contains all value related to one minute and so on until finish splitting

if any help in do it with micro VBA thats will be good.

this is what i could do in VBA

```
Sub SPLIT()
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim row2 As Integer
  Dim rw As Range
  Dim dv, fv As Variant

  Set ws1 = Sheets("sheet1")
  Set ws2 = Sheets.Add
  row2 = 1

  For Each rw In ws1.Rows
    If rw.Cells(1, 5).Value2 = 00:00:59  Then " and so on until i divide each minute data rows alone"
      Exit For
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your question.  Can you provide the code you've written to implement your algorithm and the specific problem you are having with it?

Comment: i add vba code that starts to took value of V5  thats all i could do really

Comment: also  i use jxl in java to divide the data but the code become complected and i fail to do it for 60 loop each loop extract one minute data also fail to import .xlsx since jxl use just .xls. i HAVE NEAR MILLION RECORDE

Comment: Thank you for sharing.  Given that you've asked other programming questions, you seem to understand programming. I recommend you look through [Chip Pearson's](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx) Website for how to program in VBA.  You're on the right path and Chip's site is full of useful information and great examples.

Comment: your best option would be creating 60 worksheet in advance and then evaluating column V5 and creating an index column that shows which interval they fall in, also using arrays would be a good option since it can do this really fast compared to using ranges

Answer (score 1):

So I've put something together for you that will get you started. You'll likely have to adjust the code for the exact time bounds that fit your requirement (which will be a good learning oppurtunity!). Note that you can take an approach of setting these bounds as either fixed or variable (i.e.: increments of minutes/seconds/hours, or the fixed bounds I have now)

To set this up you'll need three sheets in your workpaper named (1) Hours, (2) Minutes, and (3) Seconds.

As the code is set up the rows get sorted and placed into bounds depending on if it's under one minute, under one hour, or greater than one hour.

Take a stab at adjusting the code to your exact requirements and if you have any questions feel free to let me know!

```
Function Last_Row(Sheet_Name As String)
    Last_Row = Sheets(Sheet_Name).Range("A" & Sheets(Sheet_Name).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Sub AllocateSheet()

Dim Cell As Variant
Dim Cell_Range As Range
Set Cell_Range = Range("E2:E990000")

Seperator_Second = TimeValue("00:00:01")
Seperator_Minute = TimeValue("00:01:00")
Seperator_Hour = TimeValue("01:00:00")


For Each Cell In Cell_Range
    If Cell.Value >= Seperator_Hour Then
        Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Hours").Rows(Last_Row("Hours") + 1)
    ElseIf Cell.Value <= Seperator_Hour And Cell.Value >= Seperator_Minute Then
        Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Minutes").Rows(Last_Row("Minutes") + 1)
    ElseIf Cell.Value <= Seperator_Minute And Cell.Value >= Seperator_Second Then
        Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Seconds").Rows(Last_Row("Seconds") + 1)
    End If
Next Cell


End Sub
```

Comment: once it found any value it fail to copy it !

Comment: In that case it probably comes down to the formatting of your cells. I'd suggest going to the "custom" formatting panel, and then select the "H:MM:SS" formatting. For this to work you'll need an apples to apples comparison of time value vs. time value. Test it out with smaller ranges of data first before applying to your entire dataset

Answer (score 0):

I reach into deviding minutes uisng this code any help in edit this code so i can divide the total rows in the sheet about 1000000 row also the code make the loop only to 60000 row in E colunm. I dont know why it just took from 1 to 6000 E1:E6000 and make a loop on 60000 row any help. also how i can craete new sheet to
 paste to it inside code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

ti=TimeValue("00:00:00")
Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets(1)

    For Each Cell In .Range("E1:E6000" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value <= ti Then
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("first minute").Rows(Cell.Row)
        End If
    Next Cell
End With

End Sub
```